# Is it normal for there to be tar showing from under some shingles on a roof?

Tags: roofing, shingles

I just had a new roof put on and my wife and I noticed that there are some sections of shingle that show tar like if too much tar was used. Can this be fixed?

Comment: A picture would be helpful

Comment: Agreed, a photo would be useful. It sounds almost like they spaced the rows too far apart so the adhesive tar strip is showing.

Comment: I don't believe any tar is used when putting shingles on a roof (except for the tar already in the shingles), so you can't have "too much".

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. It's not apparent what the source of the tar is.

Answer (score 1):

Asphalt shingles have strips of tar on them that are designed to be covered by the next layer of shingles.  The top shingle will heat up, melt the tar strip, and then that tar strip will grab onto the shingle above, and so it helps stabilize the shingle in place.

[image]

Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: when I take off roof jacks, I dab tar on the nail heads. I've also dabbed tar under flaps on sides with know wind problems, such as harbor front exposures. But none of this ever 'shows'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since the installers may have laid single shingles on top of other shingles, (they are packed tar-side to tar-side so this doesn't happen). So if after the installers have separated the shingles to install them), they temporarily rested a shingle on top of another shingle, the tar from its tar strip will stick to the surface of the shingle it was laid on top of (even if it was there for just a few minutes).